# Javascript nested loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style, for-loop

I do not code much in Javascript, but I have the following snippet which IMHO looks horrendous and I have to do this nested iteration quite often in my code. Does anyone have a prettier/easier to read solution?

```
function addBrowse(data) {
var list = $('<ul></ul>')

for(i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++) {
    var file = list.append('<li class="toLeft">' + data.list[i].name + '</li>')
    for(j = 0; j < data.list[i].children.length; j++) {
        var db = file.append('<li>' + data.list[i].children[j].name + '</li>')
        for(k = 0; k < data.list[i].children[j].children.length; k++)
            db.append('<li class="toRight">' + data.list[i].children[j].children[k].name + '</li>')
    }
}

$('#browse').append(list).show()}
```

Here is a sample data element

```
{"file":"","db":"","tbl":"","page":"browse","list":[
  {
     "name":"/home/alex/GoSource/test1.txt",
     "children":[
        {
           "name":"go",
           "children":[
              {
                 "name":"validation1",
                 "children":[

                 ]
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "name":"/home/alex/GoSource/test2.txt",
     "children":[
        {
           "name":"go",
           "children":[
              {
                 "name":"validation2",
                 "children":[

                 ]
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "name":"/home/alex/GoSource/test3.txt",
     "children":[
        {
           "name":"go",
           "children":[
              {
                 "name":"validation3",
                 "children":[

                 ]
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  }]}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried recursion instead of iteration? Is that a possibility or does it have to be a for-loop?

Comment: I have tried to, but in many of these triple nested loops I am forced to write, there are tiny differences in for each iteration (ie. the toLeft in the example above) which I am not sure how to compensate for with recursion

Comment: That looks like a perfectly valid loop to me. Are there any specific concerns other than the way it looks? If you don't like it looking "messy" put the loops in a function you call.

Comment: @Sparafusile, Simply the look, I have these loops littered all over my code, (and all over the code in the underlying server from where this data is being pulled) and I was hoping there was a nicer way to iterate over a triple nested loop like this

Comment: It looks pretty straightforward to me, and easy to read. And, the best part about this function is that it's already written, so you can just fold it and move on to more interesting problems.

Comment: You could improve both the look and the performance by using temporary variables (e.g. `var item = data.list[i];` in the first for loop, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be better to look into a JavaScript templet engine:

- https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/
- https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery's `each()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to make this look nicer:

```
function addBrowse(data) {
  var list = $('<ul></ul>')

  $.each(data.list, function(_, item) {
    var file = list.append('<li class="toLeft">' + item.name + '</li>');
    $.each(item.children, function(_, child) {
      var db = file.append('<li>' + child.name + '</li>');
      $.each(child.children, function(_, grandchild) {
        db.append('<li class="toRight">' + grandchild.name + '</li>');
      });
    });
  });

  $('#browse').append(list).show();
}
```

A problem here, though, is that you introduce [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerabilities. You can use [jQuery's text function](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to avoid that, though. Or, as Detroitpro points out, use a templating engine. Also, beware of performance implications when using `$.each` - it's slower than a `for` loop, but that won't matter much unless you do it many times.

Answer (score 0):

it would be tempting to put the two inner loops in their own functions. This would simplify the code by removing all those nested children references. Although the function calls would cost time, a lot of array referencing would be removed, so you'll probably end up square. more importantly it would be simpler code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, it has a fiew methods that can help you out:

```
function addBrowse(data) {
    var list = $(document.createElement('ul')),
        li = $(document.createElement('li')),
        get_li;

    get_li = function(value, className) {
        className = className === undefined ? '' : className;
        return li.clone().text(value).addClass(className);
    };

    $.each(data.list, function (i, v) {
        list.append(get_li(v.name, 'toLeft'));
        $.each(v.children, function(i, v2) {
            list.append(get_li(v2.name));
            $.each(v2.children, function(i, v3) {
                list.append(get_li(v3.name, 'toRight'));
            });
        });
    });
    $('#browse').append(list).show();
}
```